# Flex4 List itemRenderer isItemSelected() method

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex4.6

In flex3, List has isItemSelected() method, but I didn't find them in flex4. My scenario is determining whether the current ItemRenderer is selected or not, and then depends on the selected value, do some logic on specific component in the ItemRenderer(suppose ItemRenderer has an Image component and Label component, I only want to do some logic on the Image)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Flex 4, item renderer functionality can make better use of states. What this means is that they have the default states, which we can use them to implement state-specific logic:

```
normal
hovered
selected
up
```

If you want to do something when the item becomes selected, you could add a listener for the `stateChangedComplete` event, and implement your logic in that handler (of course, you would have to test if the current statate is 'selected'). The code could look something like this:

```
<s:ItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
                xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
                xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                stateChangeComplete="stateChangedHandler()"
                autoDrawBackground="false">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            protected function stateChangedHandler():void
            {
                if(currentState == "selected")
                {
                    // implement your logic here
                }
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <!-- Your original MXML code here -->

</s:ItemRenderer>
```

This would be the way to go, if you need some non-trivial logic done. If, however, you just need to change some attributes on the image, when the item renderer becomes selected, you could just specify a state-specific property/value pair on the  element instead, like so (let's assume the images are faded by default, and when the item is selected, you want to fade them in, for the sake of the explanation):

```
<s:Image alpha="0.5" alpha.selected="1" />
```

This way, no listener/handler is required.

Hope this helps. Have a great day.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but were the states not already there in Flex 3?

Comment: Well, yes, but in my opinion, in Flex 4, you can do a lot more with them. That was what I was trying to express. But you are right, it can be understood that they have been introduced by Flex 4, which is incorrect.

Comment: I have edited my answer, in the hope that this way it makes more sense.

Comment: @RomiHalasz thanks for your idea. I solved the itemRenderer problem now. But I encountered another problem, which is about List layout issue, could you help me ? The question is posted in another page.

Comment: @RomiHalasz the question is post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11897205/list-with-different-column-count