# List with different column count

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

[image]

As the pic show(This is drawn by PhotoShop, not implemented yet), I want to implemnt a `List` like this one. It has different column count, say the first row has only one item, and the others have two items . I tried to use `itemRendererFunction` to detect the different item(the first row treat as a rendererA, the others treat as another rendererB),but it didn't work.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve, and what is the problem ?

Comment: @RomiHalasz, sorry for confusing you. I want List behave as the pic(the pic is drawn by PhotoShop, not implemented by code), put it in another way, I want the List first row has one item, and the others has two item.

Comment: @RomiHalasz. first row item is different with others, it has an Image component and a dotline component. The others only has Image component. And you see, the first row has only one item, and it aligns center.

Comment: Is the first item simply the first item in the dataProvider, or is it the currently selected item?

Comment: @RIAstar. I had updated the question and pic. Sorry for confusing. The first ite msimply the first item in the dataProvider. However, the others item is different with the first item, for the first item has dotline and align center.

Comment: In that case you'll have to write a custom layout. There's nothing out of the box that can do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cleanest solution to this problem, is to create a custom layout (we've discussed in the comments how Romi's solution will eventually cause too many problems). However, this is usually not an easy thing to do.

I will give you a rough sketch of what this custom layout might look like, so you can use it as a starting point to create one that does exactly what you need.
To create a custom layout, you must subclass `BaseLayout` and override and implement its `updateDisplayList` and `measure` methods.

To make things easier (and in order not to dump 500 lines of code in here), I used some hardcoded variables for this example. It assumes there will always be two columns, the first item will always be 200x200 px, and the other items will always be 100x100 px. There is no horizontalGap or verticalGap.
The consequence is of course that you can use this custom layout (as it is now) only for this specific List and these specific ItemRenderers. If you want it to be more generic, you'll have to do a lot more calculations.

But now for the code:

```
public class MyCustomLayout extends LayoutBase {

    //hardcoded variables
    private var columnCount:int = 2;

    private var bigTileWidth:Number = 200;
    private var bigTileHeight:Number = 200;
    private var smallTileWidth:Number = 100;
    private var smallTileHeight:Number = 100;

    override public function updateDisplayList(width:Number, height:Number):void {
        var layoutTarget:GroupBase = target;
        if (!layoutTarget) return;

        var numElements:int = layoutTarget.numElements;
        if (!numElements) return;

        //position and size the first element
        var el:ILayoutElement = useVirtualLayout ? 
            layoutTarget.getVirtualElementAt(0) : layoutTarget.getElementAt(0);
        el.setLayoutBoundsSize(bigTileWidth, bigTileHeight);
        el.setLayoutBoundsPosition(0, 0);

        //position & size the other elements in 2 columns below the 1st element
        for (var i:int=1; i<numElements; i++) {
            var x:Number = smallTileWidth  * ((i-1) % 2);
            var y:Number = smallTileHeight * Math.floor((i-1) / 2) + bigTileHeight;

            el = useVirtualLayout ? 
                layoutTarget.getVirtualElementAt(i) : 
                layoutTarget.getElementAt(i);
            el.setLayoutBoundsSize(smallTileWidth, smallTileHeight);
            el.setLayoutBoundsPosition(x, y);
        }

        //set the content size (necessary for scrolling)
        layoutTarget.setContentSize(
            layoutTarget.measuredWidth, layoutTarget.measuredHeight
        );
    }

    override public function measure():void {
        var layoutTarget:GroupBase = target;
        if (!layoutTarget) return;

        var rowCount:int = Math.ceil((layoutTarget.numElements - 1) / 2);

        //measure the total width and height
        layoutTarget.measuredWidth = layoutTarget.measuredMinWidth = 
            Math.max(smallTileWidth * columnCount, bigTileWidth);
        layoutTarget.measuredHeight = layoutTarget.measuredMinHeight = 
            bigTileHeight + smallTileHeight * rowCount;
    }

}
```

And you can use it like this:

```
<s:List dataProvider="{dp}" height="300">
    <s:layout>
        <l:MyCustomLayout />
    </s:layout>
</s:List>
```

Comment: I agree, it is a cleaner solution, and a better way to approach the task expressed in the question. This is the correct answer!

Comment: @RIAstar. Thanks so much! Really appreciate your help. BTW, I'm a newbie for Flex4, could you give some advice about how to learn, master flex4 (or any other language as example is fine)and share your experience and some websites or books(not limit on Flex, actually, I'm also interested JS)

Comment: @jason The only book I've ever read was the Flex Cookbook when I just got started. After that it was all just scouring the internet and reading some blogs (most of these blogs are now dead, or their writers have moved on to other areas of expertise, so I'm not sure they might help you). The best advice in a nutshell I can think of: learn to understand the Spark skinning architecture; learn to use the Spark state syntax; if you want to customize, learn the component lifecycle. Bear in mind that creating custom layouts is already fairly advanced usage of Flex4. It's not the place to get started.

Comment: Can you help me to make an horizontalGap ?

Comment: In `updateDisplayList` it should be as simple as `var x:Number = (smallTileWidth + horizontalGap)  * ((i-1) % 2);`. In the `measure` method you'll also have to replace `smallTileWidth` with `smallTileWidth + horizontalGap`, but at the end you'll have to subtract `horizontalGap` one time: you have to count `horizontalGap` [column - 1] times.

Comment: Do you have an idea how should i do in order to split the screen in multiple rectangles. The screen may have different resolutions. Basically I what to show on the screen something like a grid. Thanks

Comment: There's `TileLayout` for that.

Comment: I tried to use the TitleLayout and i can't scale the list to the screen. I want the list and the cell to be proportional to the screen size.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you want to change the defined behavior of an existing component, always check first if you can solve the problem with skinning. It is a really powerful feature i Flex, and can also provide a solution in this case.

So, let's begin, assuming you already have your List, you only need to create a custom skin which "splits" the data provider in two parts, the first item, and all the others. So, let's assume we have this initial setup:

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

        [Bindable]
        private var c:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
            "String 1",
            "String 2",
            "String 3",
            "String 4",
            "String 5",
            "String 6",
            "String 7",
            "String 8",
            "String 9",
            "String 10",
            "String 11",
            "String 12",
            "String 13",
            "String 14",
            "String 15"]);
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:List skinClass="CustomSkinList" dataProvider="{c}" />
```

As you can see, we define a custom list skin, which is just a copy of `spark.skins.spark.ListSkin`, the default skin for `spark.components.List` element.

Before we handle the data provider logic, we need to take a look at how the list items are rendered. This is done by using a `DataGroup` element, added to the skin, like so:

```
<s:Scroller left="0" top="0" right="0" bottom="0" id="scroller" minViewportInset="1" hasFocusableChildren="false">
    <!--- @copy spark.components.SkinnableDataContainer#dataGroup -->
    <s:DataGroup id="dataGroup" itemRenderer="spark.skins.spark.DefaultItemRenderer">
        <s:layout>
            <!--- The default layout is vertical and measures at least for 5 rows.  
            When switching to a different layout, HorizontalLayout for example,
            make sure to adjust the minWidth, minHeight sizes of the skin -->
            <s:VerticalLayout gap="0" horizontalAlign="contentJustify" requestedMinRowCount="5" />
        </s:layout>
    </s:DataGroup>
</s:Scroller>
```

Here is the place where we will have to make the changes, in order to get the first element to render differently. What we need to do, is just add another DataGroup, for rendering the first element in a custom way (this of course means using a custom item renderer). Now, our scroller looks like this:

```
<s:Scroller left="0"
            top="0"
            right="0"
            bottom="0"
            id="scroller"
            minViewportInset="1"
            hasFocusableChildren="false">
    <!--- @copy spark.components.SkinnableDataContainer#dataGroup -->
    <s:VGroup width="100%" height="100%">

        <s:DataGroup id="firstItemDataGroup"
                     width="100%"
                     itemRenderer="CustomItemRenderer"
                     height="20">
            <s:layout>
                <s:VerticalLayout />
            </s:layout>
        </s:DataGroup>

        <s:DataGroup id="dataGroup" itemRenderer="spark.skins.spark.DefaultItemRenderer">
            <s:layout>
                <!--- The default layout is vertical and measures at least for 5 rows.
                When switching to a different layout, HorizontalLayout for example,
                make sure to adjust the minWidth, minHeight sizes of the skin -->
                <s:TileLayout horizontalAlign="center" requestedColumnCount="2" />
            </s:layout>
        </s:DataGroup>
    </s:VGroup>
</s:Scroller>
```

Notice the 'firstItemDataGroup' addition, also the fact that it uses a different item renderer, than the default dataGroup element. With this new container in place we can proceed to render the elements. The custom skin need to override the parent initializationComplete() method, like so:

```
        override protected function initializationComplete():void
        {
            useChromeColor = true;

            if (hostComponent.dataProvider && hostComponent.dataProvider.length > 0)
            {
                var allItems:Array = hostComponent.dataProvider.toArray().concat();

                firstItemDataGroup.dataProvider = new ArrayCollection([hostComponent.dataProvider.getItemAt(0)]);

                var remainingItems:Array = allItems.concat().reverse();
                remainingItems.pop();

                var reversed:Array = remainingItems.reverse();
                dataGroupProvider = new ArrayCollection(reversed);
            }

            super.initializationComplete();
        }
```

What was added was just the 'if' block, and a private variable, named dataGroupProvider. This is because we will set the new dataProvider, the one starting from the second element, to the dataGroup element, in the updateDisplayList() method. Here is what it looks like:

```
        override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void
        {
            if (getStyle("borderVisible") == true)
            {
                border.visible = true;
                background.left = background.top = background.right = background.bottom = 1;
                scroller.minViewportInset = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                border.visible = false;
                background.left = background.top = background.right = background.bottom = 0;
                scroller.minViewportInset = 0;
            }

            // Here we assign the new data provider to the dataGroup element
            if (dataGroupProvider)
                dataGroup.dataProvider = dataGroupProvider;

            borderStroke.color = getStyle("borderColor");
            borderStroke.alpha = getStyle("borderAlpha");

            super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
        }
```

In conclusion, just by creating a custom skin for our List element, we can use two containers for rendering the first item in a different way, from the rest of the elements. You shouldn't underestimate the power of Flex Skinning :)

Hope this helps. Have a great day!

Comment: I really appreciate your help. You give a lot inspiration. I'm a newbie for Flex4. Your solution is almost working, but in the initializationComplete(), hostComponent.dataProvider is null, so in my view, dataGroupProvider should assign in the creationCompleteEvent handler. This is not really the problem, the issue is when using the skin, the firstItem COULD NOT selected any more. Do you have any idea? Thanks for your great help again.

Comment: Interesting. I haven't thought of that, but you make a good point. I need to look into it.

Comment: I got stuck in this problem. Looking forward for your solution.

Comment: Have you tried anything in regards to this issue? I'm asking because I it could save some time :)

Comment: Though I think this is a creative approach to the problem, I'm afraid it breaks the behaviour of the List component in a few ways. One of them has been pointed out by the OP in his first comment. Others I can think of: what happens when the collection changes? (e.g. when an item is removed that will no longer be reflected in the List; when the data is sorted this will not be reflected; etc.); what happens when the `dataProvider` property changes? (nothing); drag/drop will be broken; and probably a few more. You can probably fix these, but that's going to result in a very hackish skin.

Comment: The proper way to address the issue would be to create a custom layout class rather than a custom skin.

Comment: @RIAstar. Yeah, I tried to create a new component which combines the first item as a independent component and a List with the other items.It works, but I think it's not really a good solution

Comment: @RomiHalasz. As last comment said, I tried in another way and worked. Your idea is a creative approach, so I think it's an elegant solution. I looked into the List source code, but had no progress yet. As RIAstar said, maybe custom layout is a new way. I will try it. If you have any process, please tell me, thanks

Comment: The solution proposed by @RIAstar is the way to go. It is the cleanest way to handle the task in your question.